# Plotting data from a SpatialLinesDataFrame

Tags: r

I am very new to programming in R and I am trying to plot data from a SpatialLinesDataFrame. Plotting all of the data is as easy as saying `plot(my.SpatialDataFrame)`, however what I want to do is plot small sections of the data near to certain points.

The data looks something like this:

```
   [[2]]
   An object of class "Lines"
   Slot "Lines":
   [[1]]
   An object of class "Line"
   Slot "coords":
      [,1][,2]
   [1,] x y
   [2,] x y
   [3,] x y
   [4,] x y
   [5,] x y



  Slot "ID":
  [1] "1"


  [[3]]
  An object of class "Lines"
  Slot "Lines":
  [[1]]
  An object of class "Line"
  Slot "coords":
     [,1][,2]
  [1,] x y
  [2,] x y
  [3,] x y
  [4,] x y



  Slot "ID":
  [1] "2"
```

There are an arbitrary number of coordinates in each Line object. What I have been trying to do is use vectorised operations such as `ifelse` to identify which lines start near to some coordinate of my choice and remove the objects from the spatial data frame that do not. However I have been unable to get that to work as I am struggling with being new to R syntax and the SpatialLinesDataFrame in particular. Is my approach correct? How would I go about implementing it? I also tried to use apply and lapply but those didnt seem like they would work.

Please let me know if I need to supply any additional information.

Comment: I doubt that you have to iterate over the coordinates explicitly. What I would do is create a square SpatialPolygon around the area which you are interested in, and then use the `rgeos` package to intersect your original SpatialLines object with that square SpatialPolygon (or SpatialLines) object.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Paul mentioned above I was able to do this by creating a rectangular SpatialPolygon and the using the `gIntersection` function from the `rgeos` package I was able to get only the points within the desired rectangle.

```
#libraries
library(sp) #for the spatialLinesDataFrame class
library(rgeos) #for the gIntersection function

# WGS84 long/lat coordinate system
wgs.84    <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"

#create the bounding box based on the dimensions required
spatialBoundingBox <- SpatialPolygons( list( Polygons( list( Polygon( rbind( c( minX, minY), c( maxX, minY), c( maxX, maxY), c(minX , maxY)), hole = FALSE)), ID = c('1'))), proj4string = CRS( wgs.84))

#calculate the intersection of the bounding box and the data - this will return the same type as my.data
my.data.subset <- gIntersection(spatialBoundingBox, my.data)

#plot the original data and the subset on the same plot showing the difference 
plot(my.data)
lines(my.data.subset, col="green")
```